# Typo3 kickstarter blank name extension

Tags: typo3

here is my problem :
I've created several extensions with kickstarter on my typo3 (4.7.10)
but when i want to add the extension to a page, I've only the default icon without any name

[image]

but extention name is shown correctly in this screen

[image]

the `locallang.xm`l and `locallang_dg.xml` are correct and if i edit them, the problem still occurs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<T3locallang>
<meta type="array">
<type>module</type>
<description>Language labels for extension 'user_documentations'</description>
</meta>
<data type="array">
<languageKey index="default" type="array">
<label index="pi1_title">Documentations</label>
<label index="pi1_plus_wiz_description">Afficher les documentations</label>
</languageKey>
</data>
</T3locallang>
```

Comment: Did you clear TYPO3 cache from BE?

Comment: yes, cache cleared several times and problem persist.

Comment: Ok, then take a look to a code of an existing extensions, that use this feature. Pay attention to `ext_tables.php`, which includes **class.tx_yourextname_pi1_wizicon.php** and check this included file as well - maybe, wrong key name or wrong location of locallang.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your plugin configuration to the `TSconfig`.

Check `mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.<tab>.<entry>.` for the configuration.

You can add `TSconfig` inside your `ext_localconf.php` via `t3lib_extMgm::addPageTSConfig('static TSconfig string');`.

Here is a sample configuration from one of my private extensions:

```
t3lib_extMgm::addPageTSConfig('                                                                     
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems {                                                         
    common.elements {                                                                               
        wvv {                                                                                       
            icon = ../typo3conf/ext/pgampe_bonnvolley/wvvlogo24x24.png                              
            title = LLL:EXT:pgampe_bonnvolley/locallang_db.xml:tt_content.plugin_wvv_title          
            description = LLL:EXT:pgampe_bonnvolley/locallang_db.xml:tt_content.plugin_wvv_description
            tt_content_defValues {                                                                  
                CType = wvv                                                                     
                tx_pgampebonnvolley_option = 4                                                  
            }                                                                                       
        }                                                                                           
    }                                                                                               
    common.show := addToList(wvv)                                                                   
}                                                                                                   
');
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your tip, but this doesnt seems to work. when i create a new tab with `mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems {
  myNewTab.header = My New Tab` this works, the plugin title is correctly displayed but this way i d'ont know how to plug an element of my new tab with the correct plugin. And if i juste change the default plugin tab with `mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems {
  plugins.header = Plugins Tab` titles isnt displayed